# Is there any way to retrieve positions and educations via LinkedIn API?

Tags: linkedin-api

I would appreciate it if you could tell me the following

- Can I use the LinkedIn API to get my work history and education?

  - If I could, I would add `r_basicprofile`, but how do I add the above permissions to the OAuth Scopes section of the Developer page?
- The URL for that is `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,positions,educations)&oauth2_access_token=${access_ token}`?

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)